# How to ImportJSON to newline ervery 60 mins in Google Sheets

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets, auto-update

I am a beginner in terms of using Google Scripts/any coding languages but could really do with some help in automating data import from the Environment Agency Real-Time data monitoring API.
The API addresses are below:

```
https://openapi.debank.com/v1/user/total_balance?id=0xc146a672c85b408a9a7bc00f74ad567b7684134c","total_usd_value"
https://w-exchange-stat.s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/data.json","totalVolumeAllTime"
```

I need to schedule a trigger to refresh the information I import every 60 minutes. Therefore, I need to script my API import. I have tried using the following IMPORTJSON code from

```
function UpdateJsontotalVolumeAllTime(){
var dt= new Date();
var time_stamp= dt.toLocaleTimeString();
var cellVal= '=value(IMPORTJSON("https://w-exchange-stat.s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/data.json","totalVolumeAllTime","'+time_stamp+'"))';
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('B3').setValue(cellVal);
}

function UpdateJsontotal_usd_value(){
var dt= new Date();
var time_stamp= dt.toLocaleTimeString();
var cellVal= '=IMPORTJSON("https://openapi.debank.com/v1/user/total_balance?id=0xc146a672c85b408a9a7bc00f74ad567b7684134c","total_usd_value","'+time_stamp+'")';
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('C3').setValue(cellVal);
}



function IMPORTJSON(url,xpath){
  
  try{
    // /rates/EUR
    var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
    var content = res.getContentText();
    var json = JSON.parse(content);
    
    var patharray = xpath.split("/");
    //Logger.log(patharray);
    
    for(var i=0;i<patharray.length;i++){
      json = json[patharray[i]];
    }
    
    //Logger.log(typeof(json));
    
    if(typeof(json) === "undefined"){
      return "Node Not Available";
    } else if(typeof(json) === "object"){
      var tempArr = [];
      
      for(var obj in json){
        tempArr.push([obj,json[obj]]);
      }
      return tempArr;
    } else if(typeof(json) !== "object") {
      return json;
    }
  }
  catch(err){
      return "Error getting data";  
  }
}
```

However, from what I understand, this is a generic code which allows me to use the IMPORTJSON function within Google Sheets. I need an additional function which allows me to schedule a trigger for every 60 minutes to refresh and insert data to new line the information within my Google Sheet.

[Need insert data from json to newline ervey 60 mins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wsymF.jpg)

Comment: you can't put a formula but the value ... if not, it will update at each open

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function myFunction() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet()
  var lastRow = s.getLastRow()+1

  s.getRange(lastRow,1).setValue(new Date())

  var url = s.getRange('B1').getValue()
  var data = s.getRange('B2').getValue()
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var content = res.getContentText();
  var json = JSON.parse(content);
  s.getRange(lastRow,2).setValue(eval(json[data]))

  var url = s.getRange('C1').getValue()
  var data = s.getRange('C2').getValue()
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var content = res.getContentText();
  var json = JSON.parse(content);
  s.getRange(lastRow,3).setValue(eval(json[data]))

}
```

and define a trigger on your function to run each hour
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dpos3PJMLpZKDtJgWkxm3r7w_7__dVrhvVWAyJIRNX4/copy